# How to match different charts

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below I have two charts, the first does not have the value of calories, the second does.  (The values are arbitrary - this is just an example.)  I need to find a way to fill in the value of the calories in the first chart by matching all the values of `wheat`, `flour`, `barley`, and `rye` with the second chart.  If all the values match, then I need it to copy that number of calories into the first chart.  For example, row 2 has matching values with row 13, so I need to copy 100 calories into the E2 cell.

Does anyone have a formula that can do this?

```
    A        B        C      D      E
1    Wheat  Flour   Barley  Rye  Calories
2    1       0        0      2  
3    4       2        4      0  
4    1       4        5      2  
5    0       3        2      1  
6    1       6        8      9  


10    KEY               
11     A         B       C       D       E
12    Wheat    Flour   Barley   Rye  Calories
13    1         0        0       2     100
14    0         3        2       1     150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a column between `Rye` and `Calories`, in E12 enter `=A12&B12&C12&D12` and copy down to suit.

In F2 enter `=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2&D2,E$13:F$14,2,0)` (or extend range if required) and copy down to suit.

This assumes both arrays are in the same sheet.

Tidy up by selecting ColumnF, Copy, Paste Special..., Values over the top and then delete ColumnE.

Comment: Thanks!  But when I did that, I got #REF!in the calories column of the first chart.  When I changed VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2&D2,E$13:F$14,2,0) to VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2&D2,E$13:F$14,1,0), that worked, but I want the value of the column to the right of that... how can I fix that?

Comment: From the microsoft website:  "If col_index_num is greater than the number of columns in table_array, VLOOKUP returns the #REF! error value."  I changed the col_index_num to 1 instead of 2 and it worked, but it's not the value I need- I need 2.  Do you know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new so can't post pics... I added a column to be the new A column that details different weight measurements (1.0 grams, 1.25 grams etc)

In cell B3 (or whatever cell is directly under Wheat at the top, paste the following and then paste over and across:

+IFERROR(INDEX($B$9:$F$16,MATCH($A3,$A$9:$A$16,0),MATCH(B$2,$B$8:$F$8,0)),0)

where $B$9:$F$16 is your whole table of original data
where $A3 is your identifier in your top chart (1.0 grams in my example)
where $A$9:$A$16 is the range in your data chart that lists gram measurements (1.0 grams - 10.0 grams or whatever)
where B$2 is Wheat in top chart
where $B$8:$F$8 is Wheat to Calories in bottom chart.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Without a column A identifying the rows, what do all the various numbers in the "Wheat" column mean?  How are you supposed to compare one row to the next without a second variable?

Comment: I just didn't understand what the different rows actually meant... Why does wheat have 5 different values going down each row, they have to each mean something different, no?